# Origin of “best-in-class”

Tags: american-english, terminology, technology

This snippet was taken from the [Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2024/02/29/defining-socially-responsible-ai-how-we-select-api-partners/https://), featured 29 February, 2024

> #### Defining socially responsible AI: How we select partners
>
> […] Together with Stack's strong developer community and partnerships with the world’s leading AI providers, we strive to redefine the developer experience, fostering efficiency and collaboration through the power of community, **best-in-class data**, and AI experiences. Our mission is to set new standards with vetted, trusted, and accurate data that will be the foundation on which technology solutions are built and delivered to our users.

Among the buzzing sounds intended to flatter readers and draw positive attention to the announced [partnership](https://stackoverflow.co/company/press/archive/google-cloud-strategic-gen-ai-partnership), one  expression caught my eye–“best-in-class”. I did a little research, since it was the first time we had crossed paths, and I wasn't sure if there was a catch. It seems to suggest, where quality is concerned, this data should belong to the top tier. In addition, the superlative expression was subtly associated with the partnership. I found the following explanation on Gartner.com

> **Best-in-class** is defined as the superior product within a category of hardware or software. It does not necessarily mean best product overall, however. For example, the best-in-class product in a low-priced category may be inferior to the best product on the market, which could sell for much more.

##### I am interested in knowing the history of “best-in-class”

Searching online, Etymonline comes up empty-handed, as do Merriam-Webster and Wiktionary. I understand that the phrase is derived from "first class" and "world class" but it seems to me that its usage is prevalent among the fields of technology. While we can talk about *a world class athlete* we don't say *a best-in-class athlete* or *they are (the) best-in-class. Am I mistaken?

The closest I came to finding anything worthy of interest was from the venerable *Oxford English Dictionary*. The only entry which had any relevance to the superlative *best-in-class* was “good class”. The limited OED [version](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/good-class_adj?tl=true) which is visible to non-subscribers, says: “… earliest evidence for **good-class is from 1852**,…”

Where and when did *best-in-class* first appear in print?

Comment: From the (breathless) context *best-in-class* sounds like an attention-grabbing version of 'most reliable'.  It's (deliberately?) ambiguous though because, as you say, the 'class' the data stands out from is not made clear. As an adjective, best-in-class seems to promise much but could easily be offering much less. Originally used in advertising?

Comment: It could refer to "price class" (and related groupings) in which case it could mean the best price to value ratio for a given budget.

Comment: @Dan Yes, indeed. These are what advertisers call "weasel words": fine-sounding terms that can mean anything at all. So called because they permit the advertiser to "weasel" their way out of any plain statement of fact. Often used in claims like "the [car model] is unexcelled in its class"—meaning, if you think about it critically, that it's no better than anything else you could buy.

Comment: best in class and also, best in show [dogs or horses or other animals (?)]. Best in class is a widely used term in IT, nothing wrong with it. I don't see how it would be related to *good class*. The term *first class* is widely used too as an adjective in casual conversation.

Comment: [Classes of car](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Car_classification) are well-defined in the motor industry, dog shows apply rules for what is a class if they award "best in class", and similar classifications are used in many other fields. It seems everyone automatically assumes that what Stack communicates must be worthless lies. In which case you should maybe find a better website.

Comment: @StuartF I cited my source that's all. That the announcement is filled with buzz words is undeniable but I am genuinely interested in the origin of best-in-class (without the definite article) and its first appearance in print. The "socially responsible" is also something that aroused my sense of perplexity.

Comment: I suppose when Good, Better, and Best became classes themselves…too much in the catalog. I always waited until I could afford Better, and my friend financed the Best, in electronics (IDK why); so we always ended up with the same thing at the same time, but hers was on the way out and mine was on the way in; it's relative. Technology, whatta ya gonna do? But this is interesting and, offhand, seems more tech marketing than tech or marketing alone. Good luck.

Comment: BTW, when I hear "best-in-class gas mileage" (for example), I assume they're talking about an SUV or something that sucks up a lot of gas, usually; so connotations do vary, by field or whatever else.

Comment: In IT,  'Best in Class' is often used in the context of 'Choose a solution for each part of your business that is the best fit for you in those areas, instead of one generic solution for your whole business'  e.g. buying separate warehousing, manufacturing, and quality control software, instead of trying to get one ERP system to do everything.  It has a specific meaning in this context that isn't entirely marketing jargon.

Comment: @JeffUK erm… ERP?? OK, the "best fit" for your needs makes sense, for this sum of money, for this specific functionality/feature  as you and HippoSawUS said, but what about "best-in-class data“? Compared to what? Best for whom? The community, the user? The casual visitor? The programmer? How long has this expression been around? Since the 2000s, or earlier?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term *best in class*, like *best in show*, comes from contests and competitions.

Classes are categories in a show, and the best of the category wins *best in class*. *Best in show* is a grand prize. Here’s *best in show* from the *OED*:

> **best** *adjective*, *noun<sup>1</sup>*, & *adverb*
> **P.4.h.i.** Also with lower-case initials. **Best in** (also *of*) **Show**: the best of all entrants in a competition or show, *spec.* the dog judged best of the winners of the various classes at a dog
> show; the award or title given to such a winner.
>  <sub>[selected
> attestations, including the earliest]</sub>
>  <sub>**1879**  
> Belfast, 1st prize and Fox Terrier club medal for best in show.
> —*Kennel Club Cal. & Stud Book* vol. 6 76</sub>
>  <sub>**1939**
>   Be interested in pumpkins because the best-of-show will bring a
> prize of $10. —*Zanesville* (Ohio) *Signal* 30 September 12)</sub>
> <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

An early usage for *best in class* can be found in 1876’s [*Journal of Horticulture, Cottage Gardener and Country Gentlemen*](https://archive.org/details/journalofhortic1876lond/page/106/mode/2up?q=%22best+in+class%22):

> *Pigeons* were also a good show, the classes being numerous, with three prizes in each, but only two Pouters turned up in the two
> classes. In Carriers the first-prize Dun was prominent, and was a
> grand hen. Almond Tumblers first a capital hen, second cock, third too
> dark. Foreign Owls a good class; pen 912 particular good Blue, best in
> class but not noticed.

Comment: I don't have a library card nor a subscription to view the OED, so I cannot verify whether @Setavr's claim is true:  “The earliest documented use found in the Oxford English Dictionary (OED) is from a 1958 article in the magazine *Flight and Aircraft Engineer.*” Is that true or another example of a ChatGPT hallucinations? I know your citation predates this but I was wondering if the OED does cite the hyphenated best-in-class version.

Comment: It should be emphasised that even though *best in class* is a perfectly informative and useful expression in the contexts in which the relevant classes are well defined, which are its conceptual home, it becomes a weasel term when used in the contexts in which there is no established specification of what the classes are.

Comment: @Mari-LouA — I believe that’s a pure hallucination (I flagged that post as possible AI generated). The only reference I can find to *best-in-class* in the *OED* is in an attestation under the word *foreign*: “**1992** Emulating industry’s ‘best-in-class’ was a foreign concept for many in the defense arena. *—IndustryWeek 7 December 36/1*” I will research the *Flight and Aircraft Engineer* publication.

Comment: @jsw29 — Yes, and not only what the classes are but also who the judges were that bestowed the award.